# Install pdo for postgres Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, pdo

I am trying to enable the pdo driver for my php installation, but when I runn the command

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/webserver/php --with-apxs2=/usr/local/webserver/apache2/bin/apxs --enable-mbstring --enable-intl --with-icu-dir=/usr --with-pgsql=/usr/local/webserver/postgres --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/webserver/postgres
```

I get

```
"Unable to build the PDO PostgreSQL driver: libpq 7.4+ is required"
```

I install postgresql in that directory

```
/usr/local/webserver/postgres
```

I installed postgresql 9.0.4.1 using the bin package and using php 5.3

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Pecl PDO package is now deprecated. By the way the debian package php5-pgsql now includes both the regular and the PDO driver, so just:

```
apt-get install php-pgsql
```

Apache also needs to be restarted before sites can use it:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if that package included the PDO driver. Thanks!

Comment: Remember to execute:

`php5enmod pgsql` after that

Comment: After that, it is also needed to restart your web server

Comment: I don't remember how I solved by that moment, but what I can say now, is that for both Debian and Ubuntu what @alex say, is the correct way to install it. However I must said that versions of Ubuntu like 14 and maybe before of it, already include a version of Postgres (I think 9.0) if you want to install a new one like 9.3 you can use

apt-get purge postgresql -y && apt-get install postgresql-9.3 -y

Answer (score 28):

Try the packaged pecl version instead (the advantage of the packaged installs is that they're easier to upgrade):

```
apt-get install php5-dev
pecl install pdo
pecl install pdo_pgsql
```

or, if you just need *a* driver for PHP, but that it doesn't have to be the PDO one:

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

---

Otherwise, that message most likely means you need to install a more recent libpq package.
You can check which version you have by running:

```
dpkg -s libpq-dev
```

Comment: Please note that this answer is outdated and see the answer below from Will.

Answer (score 24):

If you're using the wonderful `ondrej/php` ubuntu repository with php7.0:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```

For `ondrej/php` Ubuntu repository with php7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-pgsql
```

Same repository, but for php5.6:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-pgsql
```

Concise and easy to remember. I love this repository.

Comment: no probem, but the real thanks goes to ondrej. He/She made PHP installation so easy

Comment: This made it really easy, just did php7.3-pgsql. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

PDO driver for PostgreSQL is now included in the debian package php5-dev. The above steps using Pecl no longer works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP 5.6, the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-pgsql
```

Comment: This was it for me -- spent several hours banging my head against the wall with: " [PDOException] could not find driver" in Laravel Homestead