# How to connect to a Redshift database in a Symfony application

Tags: php, database, symfony, amazon-redshift

I am working on an application built using Symfony3 which needs to retrieve data from a Redshift database.

How can I go about achieving this? Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by following the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) to configure mulitple entity managers.

My issue was that I was specifying the incorrect driver. This should be 'pdo_pgsql'.

I installed the driver on my system by following the steps in the first answer and comments in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180869/install-pdo-for-postgres-ubuntu)

Comment: Would you be wiling to share an example of your working connection config?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bundle [awsBundle](https://github.com/seferov/awsBundle) by [Farhad Safarov](https://github.com/seferov).

Follow [the instuctions](https://github.com/seferov/awsBundle/blob/master/README.md) to install and configure the bundle with your application then use it (example from the README.md):

```
// AWS S3 example
public function someAction()
{
    $client = $this->get('aws.s3');

    // Upload an object to Amazon S3
    $result = $client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => 'data.txt',
        'Body'   => 'Hello!'
    ));
    // ...
}
```