# pdo_pgsql extension not working with php.ini file

Tags: php, postgresql, apache, centos

I'm trying to install the postgres driver `pgsql` by adding the following

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pgsql.so
```

to `php.ini (/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.ini)` found via **WHM Dashboard**

using CentOS7

but I still get this error

```
could not find driver....
```

Comment: Have you made sure it's properly installed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180869/install-pdo-for-postgres-ubuntu).

Comment: @NigelRen i'm using centos7 those commands dont work, no packages found error